# Exception: The parameters (null,number) don't match the method signature for SpreadsheetApp.Sheet.insertRowsAfter

Tags: google-apps-script

So I'm creating a function that adds a row after a specific point based on an int parameter when called. However, insertRowsAfter doesn't identify my rowNum parameter as an int when I run and test the function despite it identifying it as an int if I remove the insertRowsAfter.

```
function CREATEROW(rowNum) {
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();

sheet.insertRowsAfter(rowNum, 1);
}
```

So what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Welcome to [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Answer (score 1):

The error indicates that `rowNum` is not a number but an uninitialized variable or perhaps a text string that looks like a number. Try this:

```
function createRow(rowNum) {
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet()
    .insertRowsAfter((Number(rowNum) || 1), 1);
}
```

To fix the issue properly, you should look at the code where you are calling `createRow()` and ensure that you get the number correctly. Use `console.log(typeof myNumber)` to find a variable's type.